# jQuery Star Rating Plugin AND Knockoutjs

Tags: html, knockout.js

I'm having a problem using this so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.  I want to use this star rating system(http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) and knockoutjs.  So right now I'm displaying a bunch of business info using the foreach binding, but I want to add the star rating to each business.  Without the star rating stuff all my business display just fine, but when I add the star rating stuff I can only get one business to display and none of the others will show up.  Here is what I have, I know its a little crapastic right now but I'm new to this stuff.

```
 <div style="float: right; width: 360px; height: 700px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;" data-bind="foreach: Businesses">
        <a href="#" data-bind="attr:{href: '/home/BusinessDetail?name='+ Name}" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <div>
                <h5 data-bind="text: Name" style="font-size: 14px;"></h5>
                <div data-bind="if: Stars===5">
                    <div id="star1" class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly star-rating-on"></div>
                    <div id="star2" class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly star-rating-on"></div>
                    <div id="star3" class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly star-rating-on"></div>
                    <div id="star4" class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly star-rating-on"></div>
                    <div id="star5" class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly star-rating-on"></div>
                </div>
                <br /><h6 data-bind="text: FullAddress"></h6>
                <br />
                <hr style="margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px;" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>


var viewModel = {
        Businesses: ko.observable(),
        BusinessCategories: ko.observable(),
        SelectedCategoy: ko.observable(),
        LatitudeText: ko.observable(33.4633733188117),
        LongitudeText: ko.observable(-111.926908493042),
        MilesText: ko.observable(10)
    };
```

So I would need to add something to display the stars if Stars == 4...Stars == 3 etc.  But What is happening here?  Why does only one business display?

Comment: It would help if you provided your HTML and Viewmodel code. Can you check in your JavaScript Concole and see if you are getting any rendering errors?

Comment: Oh damn, okay added viewModel code.  I see the error that it is not finding the closing element for <!-- ko if: Stars == 5 -->

Comment: Oh okay I see that I had some screwed up html because I had <a> inside an element that it wasn't allowed.  But in my if statement the value for Stars isn't working.

Comment: Is Stars an observable value? If so you need to say data-bind="if: Stars()==5"